# cakephp: problem with PaginatorHelper and routing Plugins, cannot strip Plugin from url

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm using the Tags Plugin from cakedc.com, and I have a problem generating the proper paging links using the PaginatorHelper.

The desired result is to strip the plugin name from the generated hrefs, because the plugin will be added in routing. i.e. http://localhost**/tags**/photos/oregon/page:4/perpage:28

This is what I have:

app/config/routes.php (to map '/tags'=>'/tags/tags', i.e. to the Tags plugin)

```
Router::connect('/tags/:action/*', array('plugin'=>'tags', 'controller'=>'tags'));
// map /tags => /tags/tags
```

code in view file:

```
<?php 
   $this->Paginator->options['url']=array_merge(
              array('plugin'=>'tags'), 
              $this->Paginator->options['url'] 
   ); 
   echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator'=>null, 'modulus'=>'20'));


// debug($this->Paginator->options[url] => Array
//        (
//            [controller] => tags
//            [action] => photos
//            [0] => oregon
//            [perpage] => 28
//            [page] => 4
//        )
// )

// sample href="http://localhost/tags/tags/photos/oregon/page:4/perpage:28"
//     note the '/tags/tags' i.e. /:plugin/:controller

?>
```

BU, I notice the following, if I set options['url'] as follows:

```
<?php 
   $this->Paginator->options['url']=array('plugin'=>'tags'); 
   echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator'=>null, 'modulus'=>'20'));


// debug($this->Paginator->options[url] => Array
//    (
//        [plugin] => tags
//    )
// )
// sample href="http://localhost/tags/photos/page:4"

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/secrets-of-admin-routing

But it looks like you are adding the PLUGIN array option to the URL. Why? If you are using routing, leave that off. When the link is clicked it will know how to handle it. In other words, don't enable routing AND use the plugin options on the URL at the same time.

Comment: I think I am adding the plugin=> array option because reverse routing is supposed to automatically take it out when the final url is generated. And it does for the 2nd example, but not the first.

Comment: How about writing it like this: `$paginator->options(array('url'=>array_merge(array('plugin'=>'tags'))));`